# Ratios of Boys and Girls with Stopping rules

Tags: probability, stopping-times

the original question is like this:

In a country where everyone wants a boy, each family continues having babies till they have a boy. After some time, what is the proportion of boys to girls in the country? (Assuming probability of having a boy or a girl is the same)

The answer is easy as 1:1 if you model it as a geometric distribution.

Here comes the modified version:

In a country where everyone wants a boy, each family continues having babies **till they have a boy or they have ten girls**. After some time, what is the proportion of boys to girls in the country? (Assuming probability of having a boy or a girl is the same)

Can someone shed some light on how to attack this problem?

Comment: How do you get the 'easy answer' to the first question?

Comment: Mathoverflow has a substantial discussion on the first question [(link)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17960/google-question-in-a-country-in-which-people-only-want-boys). The question is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @wanderlust can I use matrix multiplication to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Imagine that you flip a fair coin $10$ times. Your score is the number of times tails comes up before the first head, or $10$ if all $10$ flips come up tails. Your opponent’s score is $1$ if you get a head at least once and $0$ otherwise. What is your expected score? What is your opponent’s expected score?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is under the interpretation that the question is asking for $E[\text{number of boys}] : E[\text{number of girls}]$ ?

Comment: @angryavian: Yes; it’s the interpretation that I would expect was intended in most contexts.